# How is the "hottest day ever on Earth" determined?

Tags: climate-change, climate

The news is reporting a global climate event:

> The **hottest day ever on Earth since records began** happened on July 3, 2023.
> <sub>[Earth's hottest day ever recorded was on July 3, 2023](https://www.nbcdfw.com/weather/weather-connection/earths-hottest-day-ever-was-recorded-on-july-3-2023/3289861/)</sub>

Turns out, the record was broken again July 4:

> [image: image showing "2m Temperature World" from 1979 to July 4, 2023]
> <sub>[Climate Reanalyzer](https://climatereanalyzer.org/clim/t2_daily/), University of Maine.</sub>

The above website gives the description:

> This page provides **time series** and **map** visualizations of daily mean **2-meter air temperature** from the NCEP Climate Forecast System (CFS) version 2 (April 2011 – present) and CFS Reanalysis (January 1979 – March 2011). CFS/CFSR is a numerical climate/weather modeling framework that ingests surface, radiosonde, and satellite observations to estimate the state of the atmosphere at hourly time resolution onward from 1 January 1979. The horizontal gridcell resolution is 0.5°x0.5° (~ 55km at 45°N). Temperature anomalies are in reference to 1979–2000 climatology for each specific day of the year.
>
> The **time series chart** displays area-weighted means for the selected domain. For example, if World is selected, then each daily temperature value on the chart represents the average of all gridcells 90°S–90°N, 0–360°E and accounts for the convergence of longitudes at the poles. ...

Alright, so it's averaged over selected points around the globe.  But...

**Question**: How is the "hottest day ever on Earth" determined?

There are two issues here:

- "day" is not defined in the same way across the globe, and when it's daytime (and thus hot) in one place, it's simultaneously not daytime in another place; and
- I don't see a reason why the northern hemisphere's summer is hotter on a global plot than the southern hemisphere's summer.

Comment: They probably just take the analysis from a global forecasting model.

Comment: Northern hemisphere has much more land area and thus is hotter on average at the surface.

Comment: I would assume they calculate the mean temperature across all 0.5°x0.5° gridpoints over a 24-hour period in UTC time (as the CFSR/CFSv2 output is in UTC). So for example, the 6th July mean would be calculated from 2023-07-06 00:00 to 2023-07-06 23:00.

Comment: A day in meteorological measurements: temperature, pressure, etc. is defined as 9 am to 9am for the local time zone. For a particular weather station recording for 7 July 2023 the measurements start at 9 am on that day & end at 8:59:59 am on 8 July 2023. To account for time changes due to daylight saving, times are recorded as UTC times.